Как правильно согласовать род?
"красивое" или "красивая платье-сорочка"?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно согласовать род?

Красивое платье-сорочка или красивая платьесорочка.)


Грамматический род в составных сложных словах определяется по первому
слову, если оба слова изменяемые.
Диван-кровать.  Первое слово — мужского рода. Поэтому произносится
следующим образом:
новый диван-кровать
диван-кровать стоял у окна.

Красивое платье-сорочка.
